# How to center container using margin: auto

Tags: html, css, margin

For some reason, `margin:auto` is not working.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">Welcome</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#background {
    min-width: 960px;
}

#title {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This just just draws a blue line across the top of the screen with the word 'Welcome' on the left. Why isn't my `margin:auto` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for horizontally centering via margin is: `margin: 0px auto;` as this will set the left and right margin to auto. You need to set a width on it if you use this approach, because the width is 100% by default.

Alternatively, you can also use `text-align:center` if you are just centering text.

[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mybH/) using `text-align:center`.

[**Alternative jsFiddle..**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mybH/1/) I don't know what style you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Setting the width did it, adding the 0px didn't make a difference though. But anyways, should 'title''s width have just been the width of the text? How would I make 'title''s width be the width of the text?

Comment: @user2719875 No - by default an element's width is 100%, therefore you can't center it.

Comment: @user2719875 You're welcome, let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 1):

The `#title` div will expand to fill its parent, `#header`, which in turn, expands to fill its own parent, `#background`, which has a width of at least 960px.

Therefore, `#title` if full width so it is centered, and by default, the text is left justified (at least in Western European languages).

If you want the `#title` to have a shrink-to-fit width, you can try `display: inline-block`.

To center `#title` horizontally, add `text-align: center` to its parent container, `#header`.

For example:

```css
#background {
    min-width: 960px;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#title {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result using `display: table`:

```css
.ex2 #header {
    text-align: left;
}
.ex2 #title {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kAhnx/

Comment: Hm, okay interesting. How would I be able to make 'title''s width the width of the text rather than it's parent width?

Comment: The `inline-block` display type will (by default) compute a width that shrinks-to-fit the content.  You can add padding and a border for styling as needed.

Comment: When I make the display inline and remove the width, it does take the width of the text, which is good. However, now it does not center it anymore.. how would I center it now without adding the width: property back?

Comment: You need to add `text-align: center` to the `#header` parent block.